# How can I pass a variable to a directive when extending Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

When creating a custom Laravel Blade directive how can I pass a variable in? At the moment the variable passed to the @svg() directive is not parsed and is treated as a string:

Blade view:

```
@svg($svg->url, 'fill-white')
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
    Blade::directive('svg', function ($arguments) {

        list($path, $class) = array_pad(explode(',', trim($arguments, "() ")), 2, '');
        $path = trim($path, "' ");
        $class = trim($class, "' ");


            dd($path); // Outputs $svg->url

           // Required output = path/to/filename.svg

        });
```

---

UPDATED CODE (Based on Andrei Dascalu's answer):

Blade template:

```
 @php($svg = 'test.svg')
 @svg($svg, 'fill-white')
```

AppServiceProvider:

```
       Blade::directive('svg', function ($arguments) {
            eval("\$params = [$arguments];");
           // Produces 'undefined variable $svg' error

            list($path, $class) = $params;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for ways to pass multiple parameters, which should go like this:

```
eval("\$params = [$arguments];");
list($param1, $param2, $param3) = $params;
```

That way you can call @mydirective($param1, $param2, $param3) and the closure will handle breaking the params apart from the single $arguments strings.

Comment: Thank you - makes sense and a step in the right direction. I am getting a `Undefined variable: svg` error though. I've created a test case force setting the $svg variable on the frontend so know it's set

Comment: Been playing about with this and finding it difficult to eval and use the value of the variable from within the directive function.

Comment: @FriendlyCode. your "Undefined variable: svg" seems to come from @svg($svg->url, 'fill-white'), does $svg exist?

Comment: Hi Andrei - I found out you cannot manipulate the data of variables passed in to blade in this way. I have now used and modified a svg package to fit my needs